# Ocultar o mostrar un botón dependiendo del id

Tags: php, mysql, bootstrap

Tengo esta tabla de momento así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero hacer es que dependiendo el estado (*Activo o inactivo*) me muestre un solo botón, si estado es activo me muestre el botón desactivar y viceversa, el código que tengo esta así:

```
 <?php 
            $sql="SELECT ta.id_tarea, ta.titulo, ta.fecha_creacion, ta.id_curso, cu.nombre_curso, ma.nombre_materia, ta.id_estado, es.nombre_estado
            from tareas as ta, cursos as cu, materias as ma, estado as es
            where ta.id_curso = cu.id_curso 
            and ta.id_materia = ma.id_materia
            and ta.id_estado = es.id_estado
            and ta.id_profesor = '".$_SESSION['id_estudiante']['id_estudiante']."'" ;

            $result=mysqli_query($db,$sql) or trigger_error($db->error);

            while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
           ?> 

          <tr>
            <div class="user-panel20">
            </div>
            <td><?php echo ($mostrar ['id_tarea']) ?></td>
            <td><?php echo strtoupper($mostrar ['titulo']) ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $mostrar ['fecha_creacion'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $mostrar ['nombre_curso'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $mostrar ['nombre_materia'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $mostrar ['nombre_estado'] ?></td>
            <td>
          <a href="EliminarTarea.php?id=<?php echo $mostrar ['id_tarea']; ?>">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" >&nbsp;Desactivar&nbsp;&nbsp;</button>
          </a>
          <a href="activarTarea.php?id=<?php echo $mostrar ['id_tarea']; ?>">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">&nbsp;Activar&nbsp;&nbsp;</button>
          </a>
            </td>

          </tr>
          <?php } ?>
```

Quisiera saber como puedo hacerlo, de antemano gracias.

Comment: Una respuesta rapida es que hagas una condicion `if-else` donde si `$mostrar ['nombre_estado']== 'activo'` entonces te muestra el boton `desactivar` y viceversa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes agregar un condicional a tu boton, si se cumple, el boton no aparece 
Por ejemplo, si el estado es activo, el boton de activar no se mostrara.
Obvio, cambia el valor de ACTIVO a tu valor deseado, se aplica según el boton.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" <?php if ($mostrar == 'ACTIVO'){ ?> style="display: none;" <?php   } ?> >Activar</button>
```

Comment: Mas bien seria la clase `invisible` porque el `disabled` solo lo desactivaria y seguiria mostrando

Comment: `invisible` no funciono por algún motivo, asi que mejor CSS